# AttributeError: 'Prophet' object has no attribute 'stan_backend' while running m=Prophet()

Tags: python, pip, conda, facebook-prophet, pystan

anyone know how to resolve this issue while using Prophet library.
AttributeError: 'Prophet' object has no attribute 'stan_backend' while running m=Prophet().
I have following versions of packages

- pystan: 2.19.1.1
- prophet: 1.1.4
- cmstanpy : 1.1.0

I cannot have anaconda so i have to install it through pip commad.

Comment: Why is `conda` tagged?